# Triebel-Lizorkin space $F_{p,q}^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $p=\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces, harmonic-analysis

One way to define the Triebel-Lizorkin space is using dyadic resolution of unity. Let $\psi$ be a Schwartz function which satisfies $\hat{\psi}(\xi)=1$ when $|\xi|\leq 1$ and $\hat{\psi}(\xi)=0$ when $|\xi|>\frac{3}{2}$. Define $\psi_0:=\psi$ and $\psi_j,j\in\mathbb{N}$ via
$$\widehat{\psi_j}(\xi)=\hat{\psi}(2^{-j}\xi)-\hat{\psi}(2^{-j+1}\xi).$$
Then we can see that $\widehat{\psi_j}$ is supported in the set
$$\{\xi\in\mathbb{R}^d: 2^{j-1}\leq|\xi|\leq 2^{j+1}\}.$$
Moreover:
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty\widehat{\psi_j}(\xi)=1,\quad\forall \xi\in\mathbb{R}^d.$$
In this case we call $\psi$ a generating function, and $(\psi_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ a dyadic resolution of unity. Note that in this case every tempered distribution $f$ has the following representation
$$f=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\psi_j*f,$$
with the series converging in the space of tempered distributions.

For $s\in\mathbb{R}$, $0<p<\infty$ and $0<q\leq\infty$, the Triebel-Lizorkin space $F_{p,q}^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is defined as the spaces of all tempered distribution $f$ such that
$$\|f\|_{F_{p,q}^s}:=\left\|\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{jsq}|\psi_j*f|^q\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\right\|_{L^p}<\infty$$
for $0<q<\infty$, and
$$\|f\|_{F_{p,\infty}^s}:=\left\|\sup_{j\in\mathbb{N}_0}2^{js}|\psi_j*f|\right\|_{L^p}<\infty.$$
By using technical arguments one can prove that dufferent dyadic resolutions of unity will give equivalent norms on the Triebel-Lizorking space.

What I'm curious about is that, what happens if $p=\infty$? I've read several textbooks , e.g. "Modern Fourier analysis" by Loukas Grafakos, "Theory of Funciton Spaces" by Hans Triebel, in which $p=\infty$ is said to be a case where the above definition does not work. However the authors of those books didn't give more details on this issue. More specifically, my question is, **why the above definition fails when $p=\infty$?** Can anyone provide me some resources (links) which explains this issue in details? Or give me some key clues if possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at section 5 of Frazier, Jawerth, A Discrete Transform and Decompositions of Distribution Spaces. They provide a discussion of the case you're interested in.

Comment: @lvb Thanks for your reference. It seems that the authors gave the way to handle the case $p=\infty$. In fact the question I'm more curious about is why the definition fails when $p=\infty$. It seems that the authors cited some references about this, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Let us discuss instead the homogeneous Triebel-Lizorkin spaces $\dot{F}_{p,q}^s$. In the study of these spaces, it is convenient in several scenarios that the representation $f = \sum_{j\in 2^\mathbb{Z}} \psi_j*f$ (defining $\psi_j$ for negative $j$ by the same definitions) to hold not just in the class of tempered distributions, but in $L^p$ as well (in the sense of convergence of the series to $f$ in $L^p$ norm), and this fails exactly for $p=1$ and $p=\infty$. ($p=1$ can be recovered under the additional assumption that $\int f = 0$.) This failure for $p=\infty$ is easy to see: setting $\phi_{M,N} = \sum_{j=M}^N \psi_j$, with $M,N\in 2^{\mathbb{Z}}$, we would require
$$
f*\phi_{M,N}(x) = \int f(x-y)\phi_{M,N}(y)~dy \to f(x)
$$
as $M\to-\infty$, $N\to\infty$ uniformly in a.e. x. But clearly this cannot hold for $f(x) \equiv 1$, as $\phi_{M,N}$ has mean $0$ for all $M$ and $N$.

This might be too philosophical, but I would consider this the fundamental problem behind $p=\infty$ for Triebel-Lizorkin spaces.
While this does not necessarily mean that the given definitions for $F_{p,q}^s$ cannot make sense for $p=\infty$, it should at least indicate that they may not satisfy properties you may desire. For instance, taking $q=2$ and $s=0$ in the definition should give us $L^p$ norms through the Littlewood-Paley square-function theorem. But the square-function theorem fails for $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ due to the reasons given above.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that $\|(\sum_{j\ge0}|2^{js}\psi_j\ast f|^q)^{1/q}\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}$ are not equivlant norms for different $\psi$ is mentioned in Triebel's "Theory of Function Spaces I" Section 2.3.2 Remark 4, where he refers to his book "[Spaces of Besov-Hardy-Sobolev type](https://books.google.com/books/about/Spaces_of_Besov_Hardy_Sobolev_Type.html?id=XSzvAAAAMAAJ)" Section 2.1.4.

Nevertheless for $p=\infty$ we have the Morrey-type characterizations:
\begin{equation*}
\|f\|_{F_{\infty q}^s(\mathbb R^n)}=\sup_{J\ge0,x\in\mathbb R^n}2^{Jn/r}\left\|\Big(\sum_{j\ge J}|2^{js}\psi_j\ast f|^q\Big)^{1/q}\right\|_{L^r(B(x,2^{-J}))}
\end{equation*}
Different $0<r<\infty$ and $\psi$ results to the equivalent norms.

This characterization is introduced by Michael Frazier and Björn Jawerth in 1990 on the paper "[A discrete transform and decompositions of distribution spaces](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002212369090137A)". Ever since then this becomes a standard definition for $F_{\infty q}$-spaces.

Triebel himself also explains this in his [4th](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-35891-4) book of Theory of Function Spaces, of course the book is much younger than this question.